# How do I shorten returned coordinates?

Tags: javascript, substring, cycript

Using Cycript (mixed with javascript) via a tweak I have this code:

```
var latitude = [IS2Weather currentLatitude];
```

This returns -1.65456038607131e+25

I want to limit it to 6 decimal places (-1.654560), what is the correct way to achieve this please? I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: A latitude value of `-1.65456038607131e+25` seems wrong, also it actually has no decimals.

Comment: -1.65456038607131e+25 expressed without the exponential notation is -16545603860713100000000000. which is clearly an error for a Latitude. See [Engineering notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation).

Comment: Are you complaining about debug output of a meaningless (i.e. erroneous) value?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am in contact with the dev of the tweak to fix the values, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript `.toFixed(n)` method

```
latitude = latitude.toFixed(6);
```

Comment: If the coordinates are -1234567, this make them -1234567.000000

Comment: After the dev fixed the coordinates issue, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `latitude.toPrecision(6)`?

Comment: this gives me -2.63868e+13, I don't know why I get the e or the +.

Comment: That is strange. The e represents exponential notation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation (particularly the E notation section)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I talking with the dev to get it done in the tweak itself:    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

Comment: @EvanLucas No, the `e` represents engineering notation used in displaying the value.